# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'

Tags: python, django

```
class ShopCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Food = models.ForeignKey(food, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Food

    @property
    def amount(self):
        return (self.quantity * self.Food.price) #adminde göstermek için tutar

    @property
    def price(self):
        return (self.Food.price)
```

models.py

```
class food(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('True', 'Evet'),
        ('False', 'Hayır'),
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Category modeli ile ilişkili
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    keywords = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    price = models.FloatField()
    amount = models.IntegerField() #miktar
    detail = RichTextUploadingField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
class ShopCartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user','Food','price','quantity','amount']
    list_filter = ['user']

admin.site.register(ShopCart,ShopCartAdmin)
```

I got the error when try to entering admin.py. You guys can you help me please?

Comment: `self.Food` can be `NULL` (so `None`, and then it has *no* price.

Comment: So what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails is because `self.Food` can be `NULL` (so `None`), and in that case, `self.Food.price` of course fails.

You can guard it against `None`, and thus for example return `None` in that case:

```
@property
def amount(self):
    if self.Food_id is None:
        return `None`
    return self.quantity * self.Food.price

@property
def price(self):
    if `self.Food_id is not None:
        return self.Food.price
```

That being said, It is probably better to make the field *non*-nullable, and take a look in the database where, for some reason the `Food` column is indeed `NULL`.